# SQL - Counting based on distinct column item

Tags: sql, count

I have a table including a Teams and a Risk column.
Risks can be Critical, High, Medium or Low. Team vary.

I want to crate a query at which for each team I will get the count of Risk = .
e.g -

```
|Team|Count_Critical|Count_High|Count_Medium|Count_Low| (Each team will be only in a single row).
      |T-1 |    3         |   5      |   8        |    5    |
      |T-2 |    1         |   0      |   0        |    89   |
```

Please show me how.

Comment: Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select team,
       sum(case when risk = 'Critical' then 1 else 0 end) as critical,
       sum(case when risk = 'High' then 1 else 0 end) as high,
       sum(case when risk = 'Medium' then 1 else 0 end) as medium,
       sum(case when risk = 'Low' then 1 else 0 end) as low
from t
group by team;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Amos